# Bash and double quotes escaping

Tags: bash, scripting

If I run some thing like this in shell:

```
curl -I http://example.com -H "If-None-Match: \"da8e7e-557a9-4cbc6f2e68780\""
```

I get correct result, but when I'm trying ro tun it in my bash script:

```
http_code=$(curl -I $SELL_URI -H "If-None-Match: "\$etag\"" | grep ...)
```

My `curl -I $SELL_URI -H "If-None-Match: "\"$etag\"` looks like this:

```
$"-None-Match: "da8e7e-557a9-4cbc6f2e68780
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put the header in single quotes like this:

```
curl -I http://example.com -H 'If-None-Match: "da8e7e-557a9-4cbc6f2e68780"'
```